# What is going wrong in this longest subarray of 1s after deleting one element

Tags: python, data-structures, logic, sliding-window

I'm trying to solve LeetCode problem [1493. Longest Subarray of 1's After Deleting One Element](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-subarray-of-1s-after-deleting-one-element):

> Given a binary array `nums`, you should delete one element from it.
>
> Return *the size of the longest non-empty subarray containing only* `1`*'s in the resulting array*. Return `0` if there is no such subarray.

#### Thought process

Apply sliding window mechanism with `i` and `j` at the start of the array:

- if `array[j]` is not 0 we keep incrementing `j` because it's safe to
- if `array[j]` is 0 and it's the first time 0, we still increment `j` because it's safe to, and increment `count0`
- if `array[j]` is 0 and it's the second time 0, if `array[i]` is 0, then we decrease the count and increase `i`
- if `array[j]` is 0 and it's the second time 0, if `array[i]` is not 0, then we just increase `i`

#### My Code

```
class Solution:
    def longestSubarrayOf1s(self, array):
        i,j = 0,0
        N = len(array)
        toReturn,count0,curr_count=0,0,0
        while j < N:
            if array[j] == 1:
                j+=1
            else:
                if count0 == 0:
                    j+=1
                    count0+=1
                else:
                    if array[i] == 0:
                        i+=1
                        count0-=1
                    else:
                        i+=1
            print('i am updating my max answer to ', j-i, 'in the window of ', i, j)
            toReturn = max(toReturn, j-i)
        return toReturn
```

#### Testing arrays

```
[1,1,1] #expected 2
[1,1,0,1] #expected 3
[0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1] #expected 5
```

#### Problem

My code does not return any correct answers. For the three test cases listed above, it returns 3, 4 and 6.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is fine, but the challenge says you should return the size (of the longest non-empty subarray containing only 1's) in the **resulting** array. You've returned the size it has in the **original** array. As one item needs to be deleted in the found subarray, you should return one less than you currently do:

```
toReturn = max(toReturn, j-i - 1)  # One less!
```

You could speed up the code a bit by avoiding to have `i` step up with only steps of 1. Since you already know it has to continue doing that until a zero is encountered, *and* you have already encountered that zero before with the `j` index, you could just keep track of that index when you encounter it with `j` and have `i` "jump" to that saved index in one go.

For arrays where the zeroes frequency is significantly less than the frequency of 1, you'll benefit from using the `index` method to find where the next zero sits.

Here is an implementation of that idea:

```
class Solution:
    def longestSubarray(self, array: List[int]) -> int:
        n = len(array)
        i = -1 # Index of a zero that is imagined in front of the array
        array.append(0)  # Add a dummy zero at the end
        j = array.index(0)
        toReturn = j - 1
        while j < n:  # As long as there are more zeroes...
            k = j  # Keep track of the current zero
            j = array.index(0, k + 1)  # ...and find the next one
            toReturn = max(toReturn, j - i - 2)
            i = k  # Have i "jump" to the next zero after it.
        return toReturn
```

Comment: see my thought was #of elements between j and i is j-i+1 so when i do j-i i am already subtracting the one element that was supposed to be deleted, so why do i need to -1 one more time? can you explain?

Comment: The number of elements is indeed j-i+1, but the value at j has not been inspected yet, so it doesn't yet belong to the window. You had incremented it...